# Coldfusion serializeJSON where variable is an array of structs

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion

I want to create some JSON from a coldfusion variable which is an array of structs.  My array has five records in it (or at least more than one).  So I have this:

```
<cfset sIA = serializeJSON(myArray)>
<cfdump var="#sia#">
```

I thought I would see as many rows as I have in my array, but I only see the last element in the array:

```
[{"MY_CODE":"RR","MY_DESC":"TRAX","ABC":"N"}]
```

I want to create this JSON so I can do some ajax stuff that will work with the data in the array.  How do I fix it?

Linda

Comment: Are you sure `myArray` contains what you think it does? I'm not so sure.

Comment: Read this: http://sscce.org/. Then show us some code that demonstrates what you're seeing. We can't sensibly comment on a situation in which you only present us half the code that contributes to the situation.

Comment: Kevin, I'm sure that myArray contains several entries.  Originally, I forced it to have several entries by copying an array position several times.  This produced several entries which were identical.  Apparently, when the entries are identical, they are ignored??  

Once the entries were different, I got the result I was expecting.

Comment: No, there is no such a thing as ignoring duplicate values in serializeJSON. Please dump `myArray` and `arrayLen(myArray)` to check the array data.